# Elastic search query filtering based on nested properties

Tags: java, json, elasticsearch

Query:

```
GET service/_search
{
  "query":{ 
"match": {"id":1}
  }

}
```

this query will end up with following result from the elastic search server . I would like to filter the search based on child property in specific based on subCategories. I have tried the following query but in vain what is wrong in it ? subCategories nod is an array list i mean jakson converted List is there anything wrong in the json conversion ?

```
GET service/_search
{
  "query": 
{ 
"match": {
  "subCategories.name": "subname1"
}
}
}





{
   "took": 1,
   "timed_out": false,
   "_shards": {
      "total": 5,
      "successful": 5,
      "failed": 0
   },
   "hits": {
      "total": 1,
      "max_score": 1,
      "hits": [
         {
            "_index": "service",
            "_type": "service",
            "_id": "1",
            "_score": 1,
            "_source": {
               "id": 1,
               "title": "title",
               "searchTerms": null,
               "description": "description",
               "picUrl": "/imgurl",
               "price": 65000,
               "discount": 10,
               "topservice": true,
               "place": "100,200",
               "status": null,
               "subCategories": [
                  {
                     "id": 1,
                     "name": "subname1",
                     "subCategoryGroup": {
                        "id": 1,
                        "name": "Engineering",
                        "category": {
                           "id": 1,
                           "name": "Education"
                        }
                     }
                  },
                  {
                     "id": 2,
                     "name": "subname2",
                     "subCategoryGroup": {
                        "id": 1,
                        "name": "Engineering",
                        "category": {
                           "id": 1,
                           "name": "Education"
                        }
                     }
                  },
                  {
                     "id": 3,
                     "name": "subname3",
                     "subCategoryGroup": {
                        "id": 1,
                        "name": "Engineering",
                        "category": {
                           "id": 1,
                           "name": "Education"
                        }
                     }
                  },


               ],
               "deleted": false
            }
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

sub category mapping ; nothing fancy in it just a manytoMany mapping as follows

```
@Field(type= FieldType.Nested)
@ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinTable(name = "service_subcategory", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "service_id") , inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "subcategory_id") )
private List<SubCategory> subCategories;
```

Comment: Please share the mapping.

Comment: I have updated my question

Comment: Please share the mapping you get using `curl -XGET localhost:9200/service/service/_mapping?pretty`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure the field "subCategories" is not a `nested` field. The behavior you want can be achieved by making "subCategories" a nested field. Read about nested types [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/nested-mapping.html) and about how to query nested fields [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/nested-query.html).

Basically your mapping definition should look something like below:

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "<mapping_name>": {
      "properties": {
        ...                   <-- Other fields like id, title, etc go here
        "subCategories": {
          "type": "nested",   <-- This is important. This is missing in your current mapping definition
          "properties": {
            "id": {
              "type":"integer"
            },
            "name": {
              "type":"string"
            },
            ...               <-- Definition of subCategoryGroup goes here
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And your query should look something like this.

```
{
  "query": {
    "nested": {
      "path": "subCategories",
      "query": {
        "match": {
          "subCategories.name": "subname1"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```